# PHPWord background color of text box

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice

I'm trying to set the background color of a text both either to a color, or to 100% transparent (whatever is easiest) but I'm struggling to achieve either.

I've tried "bgColor" as per some other elements but no luck :(

```
 $textbox = $section->addTextBox(
        array(
            'marginTop' => -100,
            'marginLeft' => -100,
            'posHorizontal' => 'absolute',
            'posVertical' => 'absolute',
            'align' => 'left',
            'positioning' => 'relative',
            'width'       => 200,
            'height'      => 40,
            'borderColor' => '#eeeeee',
            'borderSize'  => 0,
            'bgColor' => 'black',
        )
    );
```

Comment: FYI 'bgcolor' is not a correct property... use 'background-color' for instead of bgcolor...

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately, although no other properties are hyphenated?

Comment: Any idea did you find a  solution ? Another question did Text box 
 support border radius/ round ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
'fillColor' => 'black'
```

Or

```
'fillColor' => '#BFBFBF'
```

you can find all properties in PhpWord\Style\TextBox.php

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this answer here it goes:

There's no answer, textbox don't support any kind of background yet and looks like it wont.
As this [issue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/403) suggests you can achieve the same results in terms of design with a table with a single cell.

Comment: does it support border radius/ round ?

Comment: @famas23 I'm not sure, maybe not. I gave a quick look in the code and looks like it receives just size and color for borders. See: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Style/TextBox.php

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the latest version `composer require phpoffice/phpword:dev-master` to get access to `bgColor` property as it's not included in 1.0.